# Apache structure issue (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, relative-path

I have a structure like this

```
/ < root folder
/Site/Public/.htaccess
/Site/Public/index.php
/Site/Public/error.php
/Site/Public/images/chat.png
```

In my htaccess I have disabled access to subfolders and set a default 403 document like so:

```
ErrorDocument 403 error.php
Options All -Indexes
```

But the problem is that I cannot get it to pick that error.php file unless I use the full path starting from root. I also tried this

```
ErrorDocument 403 chat.png
```

And it doesn't pick that up either just displays a string in both situations. Can anyone tell me how to target that error.php file without using the absolute path?

The experimenting url is `localhost/Site/Public/images`

Comment: Not sure I understand. What exactly do you want to do and what doesn't work, can you clarify?

Comment: I want to display error.php when anyone tries to acces /Site/Public/images

Comment: What's wrong with `ErrorDocument 403 /Site/Public/error.php` then? Or `/error.php` if the former doesn't work?

Comment: error.php isn't located in the root folder. And this just shows the default forbidden file error. I want to display my enhanced version of that which is in error.php. I can't use `/Site/Public/error.php` because the `Site` folder may change names and I must edit this every time that happens.

Comment: Alternatively You could try this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402140/use-a-subdirectory-as-root-with-htaccess-in-apache-1-3

Comment: You need to use Rewrite rules.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402140/use-a-subdirectory-as-root-with-htaccess-in-apache-1-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument

> URLs can begin with a slash (/) for local web-paths (relative to the
>   DocumentRoot), or be a full URL which the client can resolve.
>   Alternatively, a message can be provided to be displayed by the
>   browser.

any argument that is not a full url (http://www.example.com) or does not start with `/` will be treated as string.

Comment: That is just so sad to hear. Thank you again Amine!

Comment: :), in all solutions i can think of , you have to reference "/site/public/" in a way or another.

Answer (score 1):

The urls have to be defined relative to the `DocumentRoot`, which in your case seems to be the same for your sites.

Alternatively you can use full urls that can be resolved by the client.

That may be an alternative for you.

Everything else you need to know can be read in the manual:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument